# how to handle table relationship interms of foreign keys in golang

Tags: go

I created several tables in MySQL database using the gorm and when I run my application for testing it is not working as intended. Tables in my database are not to talk to each other I mean interms of foreign keys I defined and stuff

I tried to change the way I defined functions in my repository file the way used to interact with database.

Comment: At the very least, you'll need to show us the code that defines your tables and relationships, as it stands this would be a guessing game.